# How to force onDraw() to be called more often

Tags: android, drawing, draw, ondraw

My Android app has a class extending `View`. A background thread changes the content (buffered in a Bitmap) regularly (as data comes through USB) and calls `postInvalidate()`. When `onDraw()` is called, the bitmap buffer is drawn to the screen, all fine.

BUT: `onDraw()` happens only very rarely, in every few seconds.

How can I make the updates more continuous ?

Comment: how offten do you call postInvalidate?

Comment: Max rate is about 100 calls / sec and each time only a small area (0.04% of the screen) is invalidated.

Comment: any reason not using a SurfaceView?

Comment: The only reason is lack of knowledge, as this is my very first android try. Thank you for your help.